# How to check the number of times a word occurs in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

So basically this is the instructions.

*Write a program that will prompt the user for a sentence and for a word.
The program should check whether the word exists in the sentence and let the user know whether or not it does.
Now see if you can modify your program to count how many times the word appears in the sentence and then inform the user of the total count.*

So far, so good until the next part. I cannot seem to find a way to count how many times a word appear in the sentence. More specifically this part **Now see if you can modify your program to count how many times the word appears in the sentence and then inform the user of the total count.**.

Would really appreciate if there is some loop that could help or a function. We've been studying JavaScript just for one month.

This is my code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab 3.3</title>

    <script>
        "use strict";

        var sentence = prompt("Please enter a sentence");

        alert ("So this is your sentence?" + sentence);

        var word = prompt("Please enter a word");

        alert ("So this is your word?" + word);

        var sentenceArray = sentence.split;
        var wordArray = word.split;

        alert (sentence.includes(word))


    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the wrong solution here is an example which will return an array of matches:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: vara _count =0;for(var i=0; i<sentenceArray.length;i++){if(sentenceArray[i]===word) _count++}; console.log(_count);

Comment: try string.indexOf(searchvalue, start), which will give you the first one, and then check if it occurs after the start again

Answer (score 2):

Create a regular expression from the word, with the flags `i` (case insensitive), and `g` (global - to find all occurrences).

Use String#Match with the expression to count the words:

```js
var sentence = 'All cats are felines, but not all felines are cats. I cannot stress that more - not all felines are cats';
var word = 'not';
var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'ig');
var count = (sentence.match(pattern) || []).length;

console.log(count);
```